# How do I check for blank fields on a delimited line with sed or awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm parsing source input files using a bash script.  I'm generating delimited output in a file.  I need a way to check that each field of the delimited output is populated.  For example AA,BB,3,4,5,6,7,8 would be good and AA,,3,4,5,6,,8 would be bad.  How do I check if there are blank fields on a line using sed/awk or some other tool I can put in a bash script?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: *How do I check if there are blank fields on a line* - check and what? should they be ignored or marked?

Answer (score 1):

With bash:

```
string='AA,,3,4,5,6,,8'
if [[ $string =~ ^,|,,|,$ ]]; then
  echo "error"
else
  echo "okay"
fi
```

Output:

```
error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the lines with at least one empty field using:

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="") {print; next}}'
```

- `-F,` sets the field delimiter as `,`
- `for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)` iterates over the fields
- `if ($i=="") {print; next}` prints the record if the field being tested is empty and goes to the next record

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt                                                   
AA,BB,3,4,5,6,7,8
AA,,3,4,5,6,,8

% awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="") {print; next}}' file.txt
AA,,3,4,5,6,,8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test with a regular expression with a repeating group that fits with your requirement:

```
grep -E '^([^,]+,)*[^,]$' <<< "${AA,,3,4,5,6,,8}"
```

Testcode:

```
for str in "AA,BB,3,4,5,6,7,8" "AA,,3,4,5,6,,8" ; do
echo "==========="
   echo "Testing >>>${str}<<<"
   grep -Eq '^([^,]+,)*[^,]$' <<< "${str}" || echo "String incorrect"
done
```

You can `grep` the incorrect lines from a file using

```
grep -vE '^([^,]+,)*[^,]$' inputfile
```